# How to extract texts from html markup

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get every texts in my `html` data which is input by the user

I have `html` like the following

```
  <em>first part</em> of texts here

    <table>
    ......
    ......
    </table>

<em>second part</em> of texts
```

I use jquery

```
project =[];

$(htmlData).contents().each(function(){
     if($(this).is('table')){
        //do something with table
     }else{
        if(this.nodeType === 3) { // Will only select element nodes
                  project.push($(this).text());
            }else if(this.nodeType === 1){
                  project.push(this.outerHTML);
            }
         }
     }
```

the `array` ends up like

```
array(0=>'<em>first part</em>', 2=>'of texts here',3=>'<em>second part</em>',4=>'of texts')
```

I was hoping to get an array like the following

```
array(0=>'<em>first part</em>of texts here',1=>'<em>second part</em>of texts');
```

How do I accomplish this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are the array elements supposed to be separated. In the example it says the array is supposed to have one element. So why not use a string as an accumulator instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbey9/2/

```
var project =[];

$('#htmlData').contents().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('table')){
        //do something with table
    }else{
        var txt = (
                this.nodeType === 3  ?  $(this).text()  :
                (this.nodeType === 1  ?  this.outerHTML  :  '')
            ).replace(/\s+/g,' ') // Collapse whitespaces
            .replace(/^\s/,'') // Remove whitespace at the beginning
            .replace(/\s$/,''); // Remove whitespace at the end
        if(txt !== ''){ // Ignore empty
            project.push(txt);
        }
    }
});
```

---

I understood bad your problem. If you want to split at tables, then you could use

```
var project =[''];

$('#htmlData').contents().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('table')){
        project.push('');
        //do something with table
    }else{
        project[project.length-1] += (
            this.nodeType === 3  ?  $(this).text()  :
            (this.nodeType === 1  ?  this.outerHTML  :  '')
        );
    }
});
for(var i=0; i<project.length; ++i){
    project[i] = project[i].replace(/\s+/g,' ') // Collapse whitespaces
    .replace(/^\s/,'') // Remove whitespace at the beginning
    .replace(/\s$/,''); // Remove whitespace at the end
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbey9/3/

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't return what I need. your fiddle has  <em>first part</em>,of texts here,<em>second part</em>,of texts but I need <em>first part</em>of texts here,<em>second part</em>of texts  2 elements instead of 4 +1 though

Comment: @FlyingCat Ah sorry, I thought I had understood your problem but no. Then, I don't understand why "<em>first part</em>of texts here" should be together. Where exactly do you want to split?

Comment: I want to split html base from the <table> element. so if we have texts1...<table> <em>texts</em>2...<table> texts3.... I want "<texts...,<em>texts</em>2...,texts3..."Sorry I should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Place the texts you want inside spans with some specific class (won't alter layout):

```
<span class="phrase"><em>first part</em> of texts here</span>

    <table>
    ......
    ......
    </table>

<span class="phrase"><em>second part</em> of texts</span>
```

And then you can get them:

```
$('span.phrase').each(function() {
    project.push($(this).html());
});
```