# How to extract html and add them to the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question regarding my last post

[How to extract texts from html markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847010/how-to-extract-texts-from-html-markup)

Oriol's answer help me a lot on separate the html markup between table structure.

However, there is another issue.

```
var project =[''];

$('#htmlData').contents().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('table')){
         //do something with table
         project.push['end of table'];  //this line of codes is the problem....
    }else{
        project[project.length-1] += (
            this.nodeType === 3  ?  $(this).text()  :
            (this.nodeType === 1  ?  this.outerHTML  :  '')
        );
    }
});

for(var i=0; i<project.length; ++i){
    project[i] = project[i].replace(/\s+/g,' ') // Collapse whitespaces
    .replace(/^\s/,'') // Remove whitespace at the beginning
    .replace(/\s$/,''); // Remove whitespace at the end
}
```

Lets say I have `html` data like the following

```
<em>first part</em> of texts here

    <table>
    ......
    ......
    </table>

<em>second part</em> of texts
```

My project array ends up like:

```
 //2 elements
    ('<em>first part</em> of texts here','end of table <em>second part</em> of texts)
```

but my desired result is

```
  //3 elements
    ('<em>first part</em> of texts here','end of table','<em>second part</em> of texts)
```

`end of table` is what I push to `array` if the selector `loop` to `table` markup.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not creating a new position in the array after the table has been processed. project.length-1 will always refer to the "end of table" position in this case so it's just concatenating the next "non-table" data with it.

try this:

```
    var project =[''],
    j = 0;

$('#htmlData').contents().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('table')){
         //do something with table
         project.push('end of table');  //this line of codes is the problem....
         j=project.length;
    }else{
        if (project[j] == undefined) project[j] = "";
        project[j] += (
            this.nodeType === 3  ?  $(this).text()  :
            (this.nodeType === 1  ?  this.outerHTML  :  '')
        );

    }
});
for(var i=0; i<project.length; ++i){
    project[i] = project[i].replace(/\s+/g,' ') // Collapse whitespaces
    .replace(/^\s/,'') // Remove whitespace at the beginning
    .replace(/\s$/,''); // Remove whitespace at the end
}
console.log(project);
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way but this should give you the idea.